# Why My Language translator program in Visual C++ overwriting a file with nothing instead of the translation

Tags: c++, visual-studio, fstream

I have developed a program for translating words in english to my native language.Everything works fine with no errors, except that I am not getting the desired output.
 The program asks a user for an input file in which there are english words, then it will read the file and write the translations in my native language to an output file specified by the user. My problem is that the program writes nothing to the output file. I even chose a non-empty output file but all I have seen and understood is that the program overwrits all what are in the output file with nothing.
  Please I am asking for someone's help in this difficult time because I have exhausted all my thinking.

Below is the complete program:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h >
#include <conio.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cctype>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;


string Identifier;
ofstream outfile;
ifstream  infile;
static string fname1, fname2;
char a = (char)infile.get();

void Display(){
outfile << "Nuna";
}
void gettok(){
Identifier = "";
 if (isalnum(a)) { // identifier: [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*
    Identifier = a;
    while (isalnum(a = (char)infile.get()))
         Identifier += a;
    while (isspace(a = (char)infile.get())){
         if (Identifier == "Display"){
            Display();
            a = (char)infile.get();
          }
       }
    }
    }
  int main(){

  cout << "Enter name of the file to be translated ";
  cin >> fname1;
  cout << "Enter new file name";
  cin >> fname2;
  infile.open(fname1);
  if (infile.fail())
  {
    cerr << " No such a file Exist";

    exit(1);

   }
   outfile.open(fname2);
   if (outfile.fail())
   {
    cerr << "Unable to create a file";

    exit(1);
   }
  while (!infile.eof())
  {
    gettok();
  }
  infile.close();
  outfile.close();

  }







     Thank you sir, @TimStraubinger for your guide.
```

1. Firstly, based on my definition of the Display() function, I just want the program to be in such a way that  whenever the english word
Display is read in the input file, then the Display() function is called whose job is to write the translation of the word display as "Nuna" to the output file. I want to have a function for translating each english word as I have done for the word Display. But if there is a better way, help me out.
2. I used "char a = (char)infile.get() " because i want to declare "a" as global variable to be known and used by all of my functions and furthermore, I can't open a file outside the "main" function. So, I     searched and thought of ways but all failed!
  Please any one's help is welcomed!

Comment: `ifstream  infile;  char a = (char)infile.get();` in global space is strange (and wrong). And please fix your indentation.

Comment: And you're not writing anything to your output file, so there is nothing in it of course. Read much more about global/local variables, and understand that reading before opening is pointless (and that reading outside of a loop is not the same as reading inside)

Answer (score 1):

There are many things wrong with this, here are my main suggestions. Firstly, your code is hard to read and confusing and defies lots of good convention. I recommend you follow a few textbook examples with C++ and learn to organize your code better so that we can better help you. As for your code, some more obvious problems are as follows:

`char a = (char)infile.get()`

Here, you're trying to access the file before it is opened. This needs to be called after `infile` is opened.

And to see something written to the file, you have the condition:

`if (Identifier == "Display"){
     Display();
     a = (char)infile.get();
 }`

Why does the accumulator string, `Identifier`, need to have `"Display"` stored in order to write something to the file? (I highly recommend you find a better function name for `Display()`, which suggests you're writing something to the screen.) Also, inside the `while (isspace(a = (char)infile.get()))` loop, `infile.get()` will be called twice every loop, once to check the loop condition and once because you wrote it in additionally. This will cause every other character to be skipped in that loop.

Comment: Firstly, based on my definition of the Display() function, I just want the program to be in such a way that whenever the english word Display is read in the input file, then the Display() function is called whose job is to write the translation of the word display as "Nuna" to the output file. I want to have a function for translating each english word as I have done for the word Display. But if there is a better way, help me out.

Comment: Secondly,  I used "char a = (char)infile.get() " because i want to declare "a" as global variable to be known and used by all of my functions and furthermore, I can't open a file outside the "main" function. So, I searched and thought of ways but all failed! Please any one's help is welcomed!